# CL-WHO in Python: clever or just stupid?

Tags: python, html, lisp

I can't tell if this is clever or just stupid. I like CL-WHO and I also like Python, so I've been fiddling with a way to mash the two up. What I want is to say this:

```
tag("html",
    lst(
      tag("head"),
      tag("body",
        lst(
          tag("h1", "This is the headline"),
          tag("p", "This is the article"),
          tag("p",
            tag("a", "Click here for more", ["href", "http://nowhere.com"]))))))
```

and have it evaluate to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>This is the headline</h1>
      <p>This is the article</p>
      <p>
        <a href="http://nowhere.com">Click here for more</a>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Looks just like CL-WHO but with function notation instead of s-expressions. So I started with this tag-generating function:

```
def tag(name, inner="", attribs=[], close=True):
  ret = []
  ret.append('<' + name)
  while attribs.__len__() > 0:
      ret.append(' %s="%s"' % (attribs.pop(0),attribs.pop(0)))
  ret.append(">")
  if type(inner).__name__ == 'list':
    ret.extend(inner)
  else:
    ret.append(inner)
  if close:
    ret.append('</%s>' % name)
  return "".join(ret)
```

inner can be a list and square brackets for lists are ugly in all that Lispy code, so I want a function that makes a list from its arguments:

```
def lst(*args):
  return [x for x in args]
```

To facilitate conditional code generation, you need an if statement which is a function that evaluates to one of two results, as in Lisp, so you can nest it. An imperative flow- control-style if will not do.

```
def fif(cond, a, b):
  if cond:
    return a
  else:
    return b
```

Vioila. Now you can generate a sample page like this:

```
def gen(x):
  """Sample function demonstratine conditional HTML generation. Looks just like CL-WHO!"""
  return tag("html",
    lst(
      tag("head"),
      tag("body",
        lst(
          fif(x == 1, tag("h1", "This is the headline"), tag("h1", "No, THIS is the headline")),
          tag("p", "This is the article"),
          tag("p",
            tag("a", "Click here for more", ["href", "http://nowhere.com"]))))))

print gen(1)
```

Where this starts to break down is loops. Anything that loops is going to have to be extracted into a separate function. So what dio you think? Interesting or dumb? Try it & tell me what you think.

Comment: Well, this does not belong on SO since it's not a question. What would you like to hear anyway? It's not exactly practical after all ...

Comment: Your `fif` only returns one result but both will be evaluated before it's even called.

Answer (score 1):

You should html-escape every text node, attribute value, etc. or html injection and XSS will bite you.

Apart from full-featured templating systems (mako, genhi, chameleon, jinja, etc) the library more similar to what you do is probably lxml

```
>>> from lxml.html.builder import HTML, HEAD, BODY, H1, P, A
>>> from lxml.html import tostring
>>> 
>>> h = HTML(
...         HEAD(
...             BODY(
...                 H1('This is the headline'),
...                 P('This is the article'),
...                 P(
...                     A('Click here for more', href='http://nowhere.com')))))
>>> print tostring(h, pretty_print=True)
<html><head><body>
<h1>This is the headline</h1>
<p>This is the article</p>
<p><a href="http://nowhere.com">Click here for more</a></p>
</body></head></html>
```

And you can use the ternary operator

```
H1("This is the headline" if x==1 else "No, THIS is the headline")
```